# laravel migration error after define defaultStringLength

Tags: php, laravel

i get this error after define 'defaultStringLength'

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::defaultSt     ringLength()

Comment: plz provide the migrations's code

Comment: @mohammad post your database/migration migration table

Comment: Why this have a blank space `defaultSt ringLength()`? Please post your code and laravel version too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an older version of Laravel. You can use this method only since 5.4

You can limit string length manually:

```
$table->string('name', 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this url: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema

```
$table->string('name', 100);
```